WBADMIN listing "nonexistent" backup
Getting an odd result when listing backups on a domain controller ("TSTSRV001") in WBADMIN. The following command to list the backups on a specific disk shows two "machines", which is unexpected.
For reference, "AGPM" is a group policy management tool used in our environment. It's not part of our domain controller backup (we do a bare metal backup) and only the DC backups should have a local copy on the DC itself. I'm not familiar with how AGPM does backups in general, but there is no machine called "AGPM" in the domain (AGPM runs on a different server with a completely different name).
C:\>wbadmin get versions -backupTarget:e:
wbadmin 1.0 - Backup command-line tool
(C) Copyright Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Backups of more than one computer were found in this location. Specify
which computer's backups you want to use. To do this, use the parameter
-machine:BackupMachineName with WBADMIN GET VERSIONS

The list of computers whose backups can be used to perform a recovery at the 
specified location:

        AGPM
        TSTSRV001
ERROR - The requested operation could not be performed because the
parameter -machine:<BackedUpComputerName> was not specified.

I assumed that some other tech decided to use the DC as a dumping ground, so I tried to find the backup item by specifying the -machine:AGPM parameter, with this result.
C:\>wbadmin get versions -backupTarget:e: -machine:AGPM
wbadmin 1.0 - Backup command-line tool
(C) Copyright Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

ERROR - No backup was found.

Next, some troubleshooting:

I tried the same commands targeting the other disk volumes - nothing listed.

Running net share only listed the expected shares on a domain controller server.

Running wbadmin get versions -backupTarget:e: -machine:TSTSRV001 lists six bare metal backups for TSTSRV001. WBADMIN does not find backups on any other disk volume.

Running vssadmin list shadows lists six shadow copies for the entire system, corresponding to the six bare metal backups in E:. These should be the only backups on the system


Microsoft have royally messed with their documentation in recent years and you can't even google/bing the text "list of computers whose backups can be used to perform a recovery at the specified location" and get actual results.
So, can anyone explain how to find where this ghost result for an "AGPM" backup comes from? And, more importantly, how to get rid of it?

(I've tagged both Windows Server 2008 (since that's when wbadmin was added) and Windows Server 2022 (since that's the actual OS) - it'd be nice if there were simply a generic windows-server tag for these questions that apply to most versions of Windows Server).

I would not rely on windows backup. as an ex it technology worker where some customers said it'd been good, was caught and could not restore. I would think using veeam would be more fitted as an community edition exists

This is an enterprise environment - we have Commvault for system-level backups and the brick-level backup of AD objects (and to back up the file copy of the WBAdmin system backup). However, for a full AD recovery in the event of corruption or compromise, a bare metal recovery of one DC and forest rebuild is the gold standard. Especially since we don't need to rely on Commvault if AD is down and we can access just one DC - no prizes for guessing what the primary method is to logon to the Commvault farm (yes, there is a break-glass account for that too).

If anyone needs to reference the AD Forest Recovery guide, here it is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/forest-recovery-guide/ad-forest-recovery-guide. The reason we have selected Windows Backup as our primary method for forest recovery is that it is an MSFT product, it is documented in that procedure, and there is a single vendor to deal with. A lot less potential for "confusion" with vendors pointing the finger at each other if something goes wrong. But that's not really relevant to my question, which might potentially affect any VSS-based backup.
